# Hundreds of unserialize requests

Tags: 7, caching, performance

I have a large Drupal 7 website on my hands that is very large and has loads of modules (over 200).
I am already seeing poor performance symptoms in the FPM logs with max_children limits reached on the Acquia server.
I installed a profiler (blackfire) and the main issue (on every page) is an absurd amount of calls to unserialize (over 300) coming from DrupalDatabaseCacheprepareItem (autenticated).
This happens even on a basic page.
I am having a tough time coming up with a solid strategy to pinpoint the bottleneck and which module(s) are the culprit.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: If you have a profiler, you should be able to see what is calling all the cache gets.

Comment: Hi @mikeytown2 thanks for your reply. I have tried the profiler but wasn't getting much luck, however I wasn't focusing on the cache_gets. I'll have a try and get back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so as an example, on a standard content page, blackfire is telling me I have 602 calls to unserialize. 84 of these from menu_get_object, 206 from DrupalDatabaseCache:prepareItem and 7 from EntityAPIController::load (these seem to be the relevant ones). 

From these, the ones that come to cache_get (that calls DrupalDatabaseCache::getMultiple) are variable_initialize and FieldInfo::getFields (1 for each).

Comment: This is what gets me so confused, I can't understand where the load is coming from since it only shows 1 call for variable_initialize and FieldInfo::getFields. Also it's a big gap between the 602 calls and the sum of the above.

Comment: I’ve found https://ceefour.github.io/wincachegrind/ is easier to understand what is causing a slowdown. What software are you using to view the cachegrind? I’ve found it can ID slow points easier

Comment: Hi @mikeytown2 thanks for the tips.
To be honest I'm quite new to profiling (shameful I know). I tried using blackfire.io and that's pretty much it. I'll give this a try? I assume I need xdebug for this to work? Anything else you recommend. Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the variable debug module, which was incredibly useful in helping me find out the expensive variables I had.